# Problems about form with approval by admin in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have one error in validation.php in line 27

```
$connexion->execute(array($_GET["reponse2"]));
```

I have 2 pages the first named inscription.php where there are no error.
On the second page (validation.php) I have one error in line 27

```
$connexion->execute(array($_GET["reponse2"]));
```

Validation.php :

```
<?php

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=inscription;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM validation');

while($validation = $reponse->fetch()) {

    echo 'Pseudo: ';
    echo $validation['pseudo'];
    echo ' E-mail: ';
    echo $validation['email'];

    echo '<a href="validation.php?action=accepter&id='.$validation['id'].'">Accepter </a>'; // Il y a une espace pour séparer les liens.
    echo '<a href="validation.php?action=refuser&id='.$validation['id'].'">Refuser</a>';

    echo '<br/>';
}


if(isset($_GET['action']) AND isset($_GET['id'])) {
$action = $_GET['action'];
    if($action == "accepter")
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $reponse2 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM validation WHERE id='$id'");
        $connexion->execute(array($_GET["reponse2"]));

        $pseudo = $connexion['pseudo'];
        $passe = $connexion['passe'];
        $email = $connexion['email'];

        $bdd->query("INSERT INTO connexion VALUES('$id', '$pseudo', '$passe', '$email')");

        $bdd->query("DELETE FROM validation WHERE id='$id'");
    }
    elseif($action == "refuser") {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $bdd->query("DELETE FROM validation WHERE id='$id'");
    }
}
?>
```

The errors are :

> Notice: Undefined variable: connexion in D:\xampp\htdocs\inscription\validation.php on line 27
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\inscription\validation.php:27 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\inscription\validation.php on line 27

Comment: `$connexion` should be `$bdd`

Comment: Ok thank une first error is deleted

Comment: But i have 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in D:\xampp\htdocs\inscription\validation.php:27 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\inscription\validation.php on line 27

Comment: `$connexion->execute(array($_GET["reponse2"]));` should be `$reponse2->execute(array($_GET["reponse2"]));`   need some more coffee didn't see the prepare the first time

Comment: `$connexion->execute()` should be `$response2->execute()`. It must be called on the statement object, not the connection object.

Comment: and $pseudo = $connexion['pseudo'];
        $passe = $connexion['passe'];
        $email = $connexion['email'];

$connexion should be $reponse2

Comment: No, you need to fetch it first. Have a look at the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I’d just like to take this opportunity to point out that you should *never never never _ever_* directly pass user-supplied input to a database query. It may seem harmlesS in a testing environment but it’s just a good habit to get into - sanitise, sanitise, sanitise.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas parce que sur PHP 5 c'était `$ reponse2 = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM validation WHERE id = '$ id' "); $ connexion = mysql_fetch_array ($ reponse2); ` in line 27/28

Comment: o0 Ok i don't no. So I'll look for alternatives.

Comment: There are too many things wrong here to cover in just one question/answer.

Comment: ha , so heu ,I'll try to find some answers and if need be I'll write another post